# Doubt in Schanuel's Lemma.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

[image]

In this theorem finally I'm able to prove that the sequence $0\xrightarrow{} K_1\xrightarrow{\phi}K_2 \oplus P_1 \xrightarrow{\psi}P_2\xrightarrow{} 0  $ is exact. Then it is written that clearly as $P_2$ is projective so proof is done. But I'm unable to understand how it is clear ? How $P_2$ projective implies $K_1\oplus P_2 \cong K_2\oplus P_1$ ?

Can anyone explain it please ?

Answer (score 1):

If $P_2$ is projective, then the short exact sequence you've written down is (right) [split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma), and hence the middle term is isomorphic to the direct sum of the outer terms.

Indeed, to say any short exact sequence whose last non-zero term is $P_2$ is split is equivalent to saying $P_2$ is projective. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module#Split-exact_sequences).

Comment: Under the condition that the middle term is projective…

Comment: No, I think you're mistaken. $P$ is projective if and only if every short exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to P \to 0$ splits.

Comment: You're right. Sorry, I had misunderstood what you meant (that $P_2$ is projective if *this* sequence splits). I'll remove it